# Filtering Excel Column Through win32 in Python

Tags: python, excel, winapi

Is it possible to filter an excel column through win32 in python?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? If you want to access an Excel sheet from Python, there are different ways to do that, for example using a COM object. But you should first describe what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, I meant using a COM object.  I'm just trying to emulate the excel filter functionality.  I have a set of static webpages that were created through excel.  I would like to insert a button through javascript that when pushed runs a python script to open up the original excel workbook, filter the worksheets on a specific column for a specific value and then resave as webpage format and display in my browser.  I know how to do most of this just not the filtering through win32 COM.

Comment: Ok, then it should be relatively easy. Look how to do that from VBScript as there are many examples ([here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198703/en), [there](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/msoffice/excel/)...), then find Pywin32 and read the docs for the equivalent of `CreateObject` (see for instance [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html)). Once you can open an `Excel.Application` from Python, you can do everything you want.

Comment: It may help to record a macro in Excel of what you want to do, and transpose it in Python/COM syntax. By the way, you may have a look at Pywin32 samples, and at samples from the book [here](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565926219.do).

Comment: See also this [Python Excel Mini Cookbook](http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/)